# Why my samsung washer and dryer takes too long to dry?

Tags: dryer, washing-machine

I have a Samsung WD6000 that washes and dry clothes.

The problem is drying is taking too long, where 4 hours is not enough to dry clothes below the limit of drying (it's 11kg of clothes for washing and 7kg for drying).

I have replaced a few parts:

- The drying turbine motor
- The resistor (the part that produces heat)
- The thermostats
- The thermistor

And:

- Downloaded the app and did the machine check, nothing wrong
- Activated the process of drum weightening
- Opened and cleaned the turbine and the duct.

Sometimes (not frequently) the thermistors disarms and I have to press that button on the middle to make drying work again.

[image: Thermistor]

At the end of the washing and drying cycle, even selecting 4:30 hours of drying, clothes are hot, but still humid like the vapor did not leave the machine and got back on the clothes.

Only using the washing cycle, clothes end humid, but not wet. So it seems the problem is on the drying cycle.

Comment: Is it possible that your vent line is restricted or blocked?

Comment: Wow Let’s throw every part at it we can? Why won’t it work ,,, call a pro at this point and it may have been cheaper! The drying heater cool may have come much sooner. Wow sorry , but a simple resistance test of the heating coil after checking the thermal fuse may have found the problem!!! Learn how a basic Volt , ohm meter works or call a pro ! Vtc

Comment: Sounds like it’s getting 120V instead of 240V.

Comment: Has it always taken this long, or is this a change?

Comment: Does it have filters? Have you cleaned them?

Comment: Well, there are no support for samsung washer/dryer on my city. For those who wondered why not call a pro. I live in a tropical area so people dry their clothes outside, but I have a german shepherd that would tear all my clothes :)

Comment: To voltage is right on the wall socket, 220v. And when the machine was brand new it didn't take that long.

Comment: It has only a drain filter, I clean it regularly. Does not have an air filter as drying only machines.

Answer (score 3):

**Maybe the problem is not the dryer but the washer.**

Your machine is both washer and dryer and you have thoroughly investigated the dryer.  Maybe your washer is leaving clothes too wet.  I had trouble with my washing machine when it would not spin enough and clothes stayed wet.  They were too wet for the dryer.

Run a load but do not dry them - have it stop after wash cycle.  Are clothes dripping wet?  Sometimes a washer thinks it is unbalanced or for other reasons does not finish the cycle like it should.

Comment: That's a good theory, will test it.

Comment: Tested it, clothes are not wet, just humid. They also are hot when the drying cycle ends after 4:30hours, but still humid.

Comment: So clothes have been spun by washer, and heat works.  That leaves lack of air movement as the problem.  Go outside while the dryer is on and see if air is coming out of the vent.  You could put your hand in front of it and feel, or put several very perfumed fabric softener sheets in the dryer and see if you can smell them outside.  If no air out of the vent, disconnect the vent from dryer and see if air is coming out of the back of the dryer where the vent would connect.

Comment: Thanks, it was the condensation chamber that was clogged with fabrics.